# не могу в стекфайле docker-cloud.yml выполнить комманду которая дописывает текстовые данные в конец файла

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, docker-compose

Что имеем: стекфайл на докерклауде, который стягивает имейдж и запускает контейнер.
Что нужно: при момощи комманды дописать текстовую информацию в файл, который к примеру лежит в директории /root/aws/testfile
как при помощи оператора >> дописать текстовую ифнформацию (в данном случае ключи) в файл в системе. Файлик нельзя приложить на стадии сборки докерфайла.
Что пробовал: пробовал ентрипоинт, пробовал command:
вот что к примеру пробовал:
command: "echo -e \"aws_access_key_id = A*I*******HC3******\naws_secret_access_key = ********T*******O+******U***SM****3***d\" >> /root/.aws/credentials"
по сути, то что я пробовал

Comment: ***** - 'это просто закоментированые символы в ключе

Comment: оберните в баш-скрипт, делов-то